# How to call an async method using ProxyProvider?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

One of my services, `UserService`, has an async `init` method (as it calls `Hive.openBox`).

I need this initialization to complete in order to inject this dependency into `ChatService`.

```dart
main() {
  runApp(MultiProvider(
    providers: [
        Provider<Api>.value(value: Api()),
        ProxyProvider<Api, UserService>(update: (_, api, __) async {
          var service = UserService(api);
          await service.init();
          return service;
        }),
        ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<UserService, ChatService>(
          create: (_) => ChatService(),
          update: (_, userService, chatService) => chatService..userService = userService
        ),
      ],
      child: MyApp(),
  ));
}
```

Of course, attempting to make create `async` gives the following error because of the type mismatch:

```
The argument type 'Future<UserService> Function(BuildContext, Api, UserService)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'UserService Function(BuildContext, Api, UserService)'.dart(argument_type_not_assignable)
```

How can I await this method using `ProxyProvider`?

Is `get_it` a better tool for what I'm trying to do?

**EDIT AFTER REMI'S ANSWER**

I'm using `FutureProvider` now but it's still unclear how to feed the initialized `UserService` dependency into the next dependant `ChatService` when it's immutable:

```dart
      providers: [
        Provider<Api>(create: (_) => Api()),
        FutureProvider<UserService>(
          lazy: false,
          create: (context) async {
            var service = UserService(Provider.of(context, listen: false));
            await service.init();
            return service;
          }
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider<ChatService>(
          create: (context) => ChatService(Provider.of<UserService>(context, listen: false)), // UserService is null
        )
      ],
```

`UserService` is `null` by the time `create` is called.

Using a `ChangeNotifierProxyProvider`'s `update` that wouldn't work either `UserService` is a constructor dependency.

Comment: Did you ever find a complete solution you liked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `FutureProvider` instead:

```dart
Provider<Api>(create: (_) => Api()),
FutureProvider<UserService>(
  create: (context) async {
    var service = UserService(Provider.of(context, listen: false));
    await service.init();
    return service;    
  },
),
```

You could also do:

```dart
void main() async {
  final service = UserService();
  await service.init();

  runApp(
    Provider.value(
      value: service,
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That is the first part of the puzzle. But how do I feed that dependency into  an immutable dependant? By the time `ChatService` is created, `UserService` hasn't yet been initialized. (See my edited question)

Comment: You should update your `ChatService` such that it handles the situation where `UserService` is not ready yet. Alternatively, just create these inside your main and `await` it there.

Comment: How do you handle that situation when `ChatService` is immutable? In `create` you do `ChatService(null)` and in `update`, `ChatService(userService)` ?  Honestly I much prefer awaiting, but what you suggest is not possible: `UserService` depends on `Api` so I have to use Provider there

Comment: I really want some kind of async Provider where one can await stuff inside. I want ALL my services to be wired up and ready before the `MultiProvider` child (the app) is called

Comment: Providers will require you to always be ready to draw. Either do your setup outside of providers, or update your classes so that they handle the loading state.